# Can't install app error after download from google play store on some devices

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, google-play, apk

[[image]]

App showing can't install app error after download from google play store on some devices. The app was written with ionic cordova[the error shown on play store](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2zUmk.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

1. Check Free space on the devices?
2. Check if the app is compatible with the platform version(for Ionic its generall 22, Android 5.1 and above)
3. Clear the cache in Devices and try again
   Open the Settings application on your device.
   Head Over to Apps Menu
   Choose Installed Applications
   Find the Application you want to Clear the App Data of
   Select it, Move to the Storage Tab
   Hit Clear App Cache

Answer (score 0):

***Clear the data and uninstall updates of google play store***

This is the most common solution to solve these types of problem.
Hope it will resolve the issue